# Read smart card certificate with Javascript

Tags: javascript, smartcard

I need to know if there's possible to read smart card certificate with Javascript. NodeJS would be ok solution. I explored and found NodeJS plugin

```
xml-crypto
```

for digital signing xml, it's working great, but I wrote correct path to the certificate.pem on my disc (it wasn't on smart card). How would it work with **smart cards** then?

Answer (score 0):

There is a node.js binding for pcsc-lite (in case your code runs on linux)

https://github.com/LudovicRousseau/node-pcsclite

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure it can't be run on windows?

Comment: acording to ludovic rousseaus blog post from september 2014 there is no windows support available (yet?) http://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.co.at/2014/09/pcsc-sample-in-javascript-nodejs.html

Comment: Windows support has been added in 0.4.0